# How to use get_queryset with Django DetailView with self.request.GET.get("q")

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to figure out how to incorporate get_queryset with my Django detailview.  In the normal use case, I have this working, add get_queryset to the DetailView and voila!  It works....However this use case is a little different.

I am using a FormView to get a search value and then upon success, I return a detailview.  This working properly too.  When I try to incorporate a get_queryset to override the queryset, that's when things go awry.

Here's my code:

FormView

```
class AuthorSearchView(LoginRequiredMixin,FormView):
    form_class = AuthorSearchForm
    template_name = 'author_search.html'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(AuthorSearchView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        kwargs['q'] = self.request.GET.get("q")
        return kwargs
```

Then in my author_search.html:

```
<form method="GET" autocomplete=off action="{% url 'Author:author_search_detail' %}">
```

When the user enters a value in the search...it returns a DetailView screen:

```
class AuthorSearchDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    model = Author
    context_object_name = 'author_detail'
    template_name = 'author_search_detail.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(Author, request_number=self.request.GET.get("q"))
        return get_object_or_404
```

The code above works fine. Note I am not using a PK reference in my action reference, as it is not needed for this approach. My URL in the case of the code above is:

```
url(r'^author_search_detail/$',views.AuthorSearchDetailView.as_view(), name='author_search_detail'),
```

However, when I try to incorporate get_queryset instead of get_object with the code below:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(AuthorSearchDetailView, self).get_queryset()
    return queryset.filter(request_number=self.request.GET.get("q"))
```

Then I get:

```
AuthorSearchDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.
```

I get this is because I'm using DetailView and not providing a PK in my URL.

However, when I go to add a pk in my HTML and my URL as shown below:

```
<form method="GET" autocomplete=off action="{% url 'Author:author_search_detail'pk=author.pk %}">
```

URL:

```
url(r'^author_search_detail/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.AuthorSearchDetailView.as_view(), name='author_search_detail'),
```

I get....

```
Reverse for 'author_search_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['Author/author_search_detail/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']
```

Curiously, if I substitute pk=author.pk with pk=user.pk, I don't get the error.  So this leads me to believe that because I'm using FormView initially to get the DetailView success_url...that there is a problem with the pk reference in the FormView. It doesn't know about the PK.

Answer (score 2):

So after too much thinking about this one...turns out I was overthinking it...

I just needed to update my get_object to the filtered criteria...

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    return get_object_or_404(Author, request_number=self.request.GET.get("q"),user=self.request.user,id="1")
    return get_object_or_404
```

Added user and ID to the filter criteria of get_object.